# react-native-router-flux prevent multiple scenes opening

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-router-flux

Is there any way to globally prevent navigation to the same scene, if the user taps multiple times on a button that redirects to a new scene?

I'm having some success with checking the current scene and navigating only if it differs, but i would rather have a global solution if possible.

```
if (Actions.currentScene !== 'moreModal') {
     Actions.moreModal({ showMore: true, doc: item })
}
```

Is it possible to have this sort of check globally, before every redirect or is there any other way to prevent multiple scenes from opening using     react-native-router-flux v4.0.6

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can use redux states and disabled attribute of <Button>. So when a button is tapped then redux state turns to true and all buttons are disabled and when scene is changed then redux state changes back to false so that buttons are visible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, ended up rewriting the routing using React-navigation as it fixes some issues from flux.